# Are there organized groups of Force users other than the Jedi and Sith?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force

In The Force Awakens Maz Kanata says

> I am no Jedi, but I know the Force.

Are there any other groups who have learned to use the Force, or is every non Jedi/Sith force sensitive completely untrained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between canon and Legends, there are plenty of Force user organizations. Here's a list:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3AForce-based_organizations

From current Disney canon, the Dathomir Nightsisters or witches were featured in the Clone Wars cartoon series, which is considered current official canon.

Comment: What about the Church of the Force they introduced in the new movie, _The Force Awakens_? You also did not mention the Knights of Ren or Snoke.

Comment: According to Wookiepedia, the Church of the Force are pro-Jedi worshippers of the Force. It's like the Jedi are Gautama Buddha and a minority of Buddhists, who see it as a spiritual philosophy, and the Church of the Force are the majority of Buddhists who see Buddhism as a religion made up of humans who achieved godhood. The Church are virtually all non-Force-sensitive, but they support and worship the Jedi. They existed since the days of the Old Republic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

There are the [Knights of Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren).

> The Knights of Ren was a dark side organization that operated under the command of Snoke, the Supreme Leader of the First Order. Kylo Ren was a member of the organization.

Historically:

> The Knights of Ren operated in the decades following the Galactic Civil War. They were under the command of Supreme Leader Snoke, who used them as a tool of the dark side of the Force alongside the First Order.